# Splunk boolean operators for <input type="text">

Tags: splunk

Is it possible to use boolean operators for a text input?

Instead of `Apple` I want `Apple | Banana`

Comment: please explain yourself better

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

`Apple OR Banana` will works for your case.

Splunk support `OR, AND, NOT` must be uppercase.
Your can use parentheses for condition grouping.